# Android Matrix's setLookAtM results in a division by zero breaking it

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es

I am using Android's Matrix class to provide me with the needed methods for doing matrix transformations, however now when I am using it with specific parameters, it'll result in a division by zero breaking the rest of calculations and therefore setting the camera pointing from nowhere to nowhere..

I am calling Matrix's `setLookAtM` with the following parameters:

```
eyeX: 0,
eyeY: 0,
eyeZ: -10.9

centerX: 0,
centerY: 0,
centerZ: 5

upX: 0,
upY: 0,
upZ: 1
```

therefore looking from -10.0 Z to 5 Z, Z pointing upwards, meaning looking the model from below, right?

However when the methods doing the calculation, when normalizing something called 's', it divides by zero, as the length of s is apparently zero.

Is the implementation wrong, or is there just something really dummy I don't see here?

The setLookAtM method can be consulted [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/opengl/Matrix.java/?v=source) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set Up to be what is Up in your world space (i.e. the oppposite of the direction that gravity would be applied). You need the Up vector to be what you want Up to be from the camera's perspective - i.e. imagine your camera object has a small stick pointing straight up out the top of it, what direction does the stick point? It's never the direction the lens is pointing.

When the camera is pointing directly upwards, it still has the freedom to twist/rotate around the z-axis. The Up vector is going to define that rotation.